# Extracting one parameter from each row of a dataframe containing a list within a list per row in R

Tags: r, list, subset, data-extraction

I have a dataframe with one column where each row contains a list, which in itself contains a list.

This looks something like this per row: *list(statistic = c(x = 10.69), parameter = c(df = 4.63), p.value = c(P = 0.05))*

To explain the structure of df somehow more:

```
row1<-list(statistic = c(x = 10.69), parameter = c(df = 4.63), p.value = c(P = 0.05)) 
row2<-list(statistic = c(x = 10.69), parameter = c(df = 4.63), p.value = c(P = 2.5))
...
row300<-row1<-list(statistic = c(x = 10.69), parameter = c(df = 4.63), p.value = c(P = 4.6))  

df<-rbind(row1, row2, ... , row300) #this is the dataframe I have
```

The only thing of interest for me is the p-value which is why I would like to extract this somehow so that ideally, I want to create a dataframe that has the same amount of rows as the original dataframe and each row contains the p.value, meaning what's in the list for p.value so "*P = 0.05*" in this case.

So to come back to the above code example: what I need is a new dataframe that contains the extracted p.value in each row so that the output of calling a row would be

```
df2[1] 0.05 df2[2] 2.5 ... df2[300] 4.6
```

Extracting the value I need for one row works fine like this: `df[[1]][[1]][['p.value']]`

However when I want to do this for each of the 300 rows of the dataframe it does not work. I was thinking about a for loop where I extract each p.value per row and subset them in a new dataframe:

```
x<-1:300
for(i in x){
  one<-data.frame
  one<-rbind(df[[1]][[i]][['p.value']])
}
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean.. since I can not manage to extract that value. but if we call the initial df I was describing with a list within a list per row as df1 then my expected output would be df2 with one column, same amount of rows as df1 and each row containing the extracted parameter so whatever is in the list of p.value (that in turn is in a list as you can see).
sorry if that is not clear. Let me know what I can specify

Comment: Can you just post what is the input you have and expected output.

Comment: I assume you want to convert nested list to different columns. You probably are looking for `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sapply` like this -

```
p_values <- sapply(df, function(x) x[[1]][['p.value']])
```